# Rationalizing the denominator of $\frac{\sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {x-3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

ok, so im reviewing for a math test and the following question is from the practice final exam.

> Rationalize the denominator in the example:
> $$\frac{\sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {x-3}}$$

After multiplying both the numeration and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator, I got $$\frac{\sqrt {2x+6}}{x-3}$$

But, in the answer key the answer is  $$\frac{\sqrt {2x-6}}{x-3}$$

The problem looks quite simple, but I'm not sure what is the answer.

Comment: Is it $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x}-3}$ or $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x-3}}$? If it is the second, then the answer key is right.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes is the second, but where did the -6 came from?

Comment: What is $-3$ multiplied by $2$?

Comment: Multiplying the $\sqrt{2}$ on top by $\sqrt{x-3}$, we get $\sqrt{2x-6}$.

Comment: But, don't we have to multiply by the conjugate which is +3?

Comment: No, multiplying by its conjugate is (I think) only for denominators such as $\sqrt{x}-3$. Otherwise, if it's under a radical, we can just square it to rationalize the denominator

Comment: We multiply by $\sqrt{x}+3$ if the denominator is $\sqrt{x}-3$, but it isn't.

Comment: oh ok, That's where i was confused about. thanks

Comment: You're confusing how to rationalize the denominator containing complex numbers with rationalizing denominators containing radicals. If the denominator has complex numbers, then you multiply by the denominator's complex conjugate _because_ that removes the complex terms from the denominator. For a denominator with a square root, how would you get rid of the square root term? Square it! There is no "conjugate" of a radical expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x-3}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-3}\cdot\sqrt{x-3}}=\frac{\sqrt{2\cdot(x-3)}}{\left(\sqrt{x-3}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2x-6}}{x-3}$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer key is right (it's you): You must have multiplied numerator by $\sqrt{x-3}$, not $\sqrt{x+3}$.

Answer (score 1):

You multiply by the conjugate of the denominator when the denominator has two different square root radicals or a square root radical and a rational term. Compare the following:

$\color{maroon}{\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{x-3}}\not=\dfrac{\sqrt{2(x+3)}}{x-3}}$

$\color{blue}{\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt x-\sqrt3}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt x+\sqrt3)}{x-3}}$